# CSS - positioning background image in anchor breaks layout

Tags: html, css, positioning, background-image

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HPF9b/)

I've got a BG Image attached to a link with the class `selectedlink`

The Image shows, but as I position it down, it disappears outside the link's visual parameters. It's like the `href` is a window to the image.

Here's the code:

**CSS:**

```css
div#intnavIcons a.selectedlink { 
    color: #900404; 
    font-size:11px; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    padding:#FFF; 
    text-decoration:underline; 
    background: url("/images/nav/bg-nav-current.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<div id="intnavIcons">
   <a class="selectedlink">This is selected</a>
   <a>This is not selected</a>
   <a>This is not selected</a>
   <a>This is not selected</a>
</div>
```

Can anyone see if I'm missing something in my style for keeping the image above the href?

For moving it farther down, I'm just adding `background-position: 0px 10px;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background image is limited to the box of the element (the specific box depends on the `background-clip` style). If you're trying to move it down, it will start disappearing when it hits the bottom of the box.

You may want to try adding `padding-bottom:10px`.

I also notice you have `padding:#FFF`, which makes no sense. Did you mean `background-color`?

Comment: Hmm, not sure how I missed the `padding:#FFF`, how embarrassing. 
Well, you're right, the `padding-bottom` worked.